# Swapping two images with specific path

Tags: android, android-animation

Animation for swapping two images with specific path.

Comment: This question needs improvement. Please elaborate and specify what you mean by "specific path".

Comment: @Jeeva: Please put some efforts in your question. Look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [frame animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#frame-animation). This requires you to have you images as resources inside your project.